# Shadowed Variable Issue Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I'm running into a problem with a break being thrown in my Qt5 application, when I'm trying to implement a DBSCAN.

So I cracked open the debugger to try to figure out what might be causing the issue, and it says I have two copies of the same variable in scope, one called `index` and another called `index <shadowed 1>`. I don't understand how I could have another copy of the `index` variable in scope? They both hold 2 different values, and the one that doesn't have the `<shadowed 1>` part in it has members that point to memory access error locations, so I assume this is the one being used.

```
QMap<int, Point*> kDistPlot;
for (int i = 0; i < points->size(); i++)
{
    Point *point = points->at(i);
    QMap<int, Point*> pointDistanceList;
    for (int j = 0; j < points->size(); j++)
    {
        if (i == j)
            continue;
             Point *distPoint = points->at(j);   
        int dist = distance(point, distPoint); 
        Q_ASSERT_X(dist >= 0, __FUNCTION__, "Distance can't be negative...");
        pointDistanceList.insert(dist, distPoint);
    }
    QMap<int, Point*>::const_iterator index = pointDistanceList.begin();
    index += k - 1; 

    Point* kPoint = (*index);  //this is where the error is
    int kDist = index.key(); 
    kDistPlot.insert(kDist, kPoint);  
}
```

It triggers this exception, inside the QMap class:

```
 Stopped in thread 1 by: Exception at 0x581c79e8, code: 0xc0000005: read access violation at: 0x0, flags=0x0(first chance)
```

Can anyone explain this? I'm thoroughly confused.

Comment: Do you have any other variables named index? Like member variables? (I'm assuming this code is in a class method)

Comment: Nope, no member variables are named index.

Comment: `QMap<int, Point*>::const_iterator index = pointDistanceList.begin();` is the only defined `index` which I see.

Comment: Could you please include the *actual* error message?

Comment: The most likely cause of that error is that you're dereferencing an invalid iterator (past the end). Probably has nothing to do with the shadowing.

Comment: From the error you've shown, you are dereferencing some iterator/pointer that points to some location you aren't supposed to read.

Comment: This `index += k - 1;` is highly suspicious to me. If `k` is 0 you'll be moving the iterator backwards outside of it's range (index -1). Are you absolutely sure `k` will be at least of value 1? It's not modified anywhere in the code you've shown.

Comment: k is an integer that is always equal to 5.

Comment: Ok and are you sure the list is long enough? In any case the problem is most likely elsewhere in the code.

Comment: *"k is an integer that is always equal to 5."* O `k`. Past the end iterator problem. I recommend that you reformulate your program logic or at least you could do some checking to prevent these kinds of problems from happening.

Comment: IN rare cases debugger can lie to you and confuse type of variables. I had this happen just once. Also you should mention your compiler, and in whose code (yours or Qt code) or which file it happens.

Comment: Borgleader, that was it. It was getting multiple entries of `0`, which made the list have only a single item, since the `QMap` over-writes any repeats. So `k` was pushing it past the end. Thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: @user1000229: As far as I can tell, k is unintialized in your program.

Comment: As you're already using a debugger, post a backtrace.

Comment: @user1000229: If your question has been answered, please post an answer to your question and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem ended up being that the pointDistanceList QMap was too short, so moving the index forward overshot the end of the map. The QMap was too short because repeat key values are overwritten when using the `insert` method, rather than the `insertMulti` method. This was corrected by changing the `*.insert(key, value` to `*.insertMulti(key, value)`.